# Salesforce python Query by Name to get Opportunity ID

Tags: python, excel, salesforce

I have a list of Names in excel that I need to search for the Opportunity ID.  I have got it to work for just one name on the list using Python beatbox, but I'm unsure of how I take this massive excel list of names (Which probably aren't spelled exact) and retrieve the Opportunity ID?  Any Ideas I could try?

```
query_result = svc.query("select id, Name from opportunity where Name like 'Customer A Tire Place%'")
for rec in query_result[sf.records:]:
...     print str(rec[2]) + " : " + str(rec[3])
...
00xx000000XXXJbXXX : Customer A Tire Place
```

Thanks for your time,

DK

Comment: If you're using Excel on windows, checkout the office toolkit it gives you VBA access to the salesforce API, so you could do all this in excel, rather than trying to exec python from excel. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/

Comment: By the way you can ask Salesforce questions directly on [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)